# How to Add Nested Routes in ReactJS - React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Router Defined in my Main Component.
I Want to Render components inside this Main Component via react router.
Every time any Route gets rendered, I want to have Main Component which is the Navbar get rendered too on the Top.
How do I route them??

Approach 1:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './actions/sidebartoggleActions'
import FirstDashboard from './_layouts/views/firstDashboard';
import SecondDashboard from './_layouts/views/secondDashboard';
import ThirdDashboard from './_layouts/views/thirdDashboard';
import FourthDashboard from './_layouts/views/fourthDashboard';
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
              <div>
                    <Route path='/' exact strict component={Main} />
                     <Route path='/overview1' exact strict component={FirstDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview2' exact strict component={SecondDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview3' exact strict component={ThirdDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview4' exact strict component={FourthDashboard} />
              </div>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Approach 2 :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './actions/sidebartoggleActions'
import FirstDashboard from './_layouts/views/firstDashboard';
import SecondDashboard from './_layouts/views/secondDashboard';
import ThirdDashboard from './_layouts/views/thirdDashboard';
import FourthDashboard from './_layouts/views/fourthDashboard';
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
              <div>
                     <App />
                     <Route path='/overview1' exact strict component={FirstDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview2' exact strict component={SecondDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview3' exact strict component={ThirdDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview4' exact strict component={FourthDashboard} />
              </div>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: what do you mean by nested routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution, I nested the Routes inside  Component and then calling {props.this.children} inside Index component , solved my problems.
I refered - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes

```
const Main = () => (


        <Provider store={store}>

          <Router>
                <Switch>
                     <Index>
                     <Route  path='/overview1' component={FirstDashboard} />
                     <Route  path='/overview2'  component={SecondDashboard} />
                     <Route  path='/overview3'  component={ThirdDashboard} />
                     <Route  path='/overview4'  component={FourthDashboard} />
                     </Index>
                </Switch>

          </Router>

        </Provider>

)
export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          <Router>
              <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Route path='/' exact strict component={Main} />
                     <Route path='/overview1' exact strict component={FirstDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview2' exact strict component={SecondDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview3' exact strict component={ThirdDashboard} />
                     <Route path='/overview4' exact strict component={FourthDashboard} />
              </div>
          </Router>
```

This should be fine. Doing so will ensure that whatever route is used it will always come below your header.

Comment: Thanks but i wanted a nested routing solution , reading this solved my issues - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes